# Are there any grids to help represent 3D dimensions in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

If I try to create a 3D effect in Photoshop (or on paper), I always get it wrong. I remember how easy it was to create cubes in graph paper, but hard in plain paper.

I wonder is there are any grids available to help me with this? [This grid for example](http://pinterest.com/pin/201606520792443216/) looks like what I am looking for, but it seems to be for a particular purpose. Are there any other Photoshop grid to create these 3D effects?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Photoshop do you have, as 3D is built in and you can create 3D objects (meshes) in Photoshop using the Repoussé/Extrude function in the 3D menu.  You can also load other 3D models or other assets into Photoshop for rendering and compositing.